# Change " to `` or '' depending on whether it's typed after a space or non-space

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex, abbreviations

The usecase is LaTeX, which I write using VimTeX.

To make double quoted `words` one would write ``` ``words'' ```.

However, I'm much more used, from many other contexts (both prose and code), to type <kbd>"</kbd> for both opening and closing double quotes, and I often forget I have to press <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>.

So I'd like a way to change `"` to ``` `` ``` or `''` depending on whether it's preceded by a space (or tab) or not.

So far I've come up with the solution I propose in the self answer, but I'd like to know whether there's something better.

Comment: As far as I recall, using TeX ligatures is discouraged in modern (Unicode-aware) implementations of LaTeX. So the solution is to either use the proper Unicode quotes or a package like [csquotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes?lang=en) that handles them for you. Just my two cents and definitely offtopic here.

Comment: @Friedrich, I didn't know of this "discouragement", so it's good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've come up with,

```
inoremap <buffer> <expr> " <sid>expand_double_quote()
fun! s:expand_double_quote()
  if col('.') < 2 || getline('.')[col('.') - 2 ] == ' '
    return "``"
  else
    return "''"
  endif
endf
```

which I've put in `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`.